# Jython - how to assign a reverse value

Tags: jython

I need to convert the amount field in column 4 of a load file to be the opposite sign. I.e value of 100.54 needs to be stored as -100.54 and a value of say -23.50 needs to be stored as 23.50. I have tried using - to amount read in and also multiplying by -1 by this doesn't 't work. Can anyone help?

Comment: how about posting the code you've tried?

Comment: I've resolved it now so ticket closed.